# get the first 5 characters from each line in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, cut

Here is my **sample.txt** file it contains following

```
31113    70:54:D2 - a-31003
31114    70:54:D2 - b-31304
31111    4C:72:B9 - c-31303
31112    4C:72:B9 - d-31302
```

I have to write the shell script in that I am passing first 5 characters (eg 31113) as input id to other script. For this I have tried this

```
#!/bin/sh
filename='sample.txt'
filelines=`cat $filename`
while read -r line
do
  id= cut -c-5 $line
  echo $id
  #code for passing id to other script file as parameter
done < "$filename"
```

but it is not working this gives me error as

```
cut: 31113: No such file or directory
cut: 70:54:D2 No such file or directory
31114
31111
31112
: No such file or directory
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to use `cut` this way, you need to use [redirection `<<<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) (a here string) like:

```
var=$(cut -c-5 <<< "$line")
```

Note the use of `var=$(command)` expression instead of `id= cut -c-5 $line`. This is the way to save the command into a variable.

Also, use `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh` to have it working.

---

Full code that is working to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='sample.txt'
while read -r line
do
  id=$(cut -c-5 <<< "$line")
  echo $id
  #code for passing id to other script file as parameter
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: It does work, but this is not the idiomatic way to write this!

Comment: Small semantics note, that's typically referred to as "redirection" not "indirection." ("indirection" is usually used to mean "nonlinear paths through the code")

Comment: more understandable:`cut -c -5` only prints the first 5 characters. This is even better to read: `cut -c 1-5`

Answer (score 29):

Well, its a one-liner `cut -c-5 sample.txt`. Example:

```
$ cut -c-5 sample.txt 
31113
31114
31111
31112
```

From there-on, you can pipe it to any other script or command:

```
$ cut -c-5 sample.txt | while read line; do echo Hello $line; done
Hello 31113
Hello 31114
Hello 31111
Hello 31112
```

Answer (score 8):

Rather than piping `echo` into `cut`, just pipe the output of `cut` directly to the while loop:

```
cut -c 1-5 sample.txt |
while read -r id; do
  echo $id
  #code for passing id to other script file as parameter
done
```

Comment: Why do you need the while loop?

Comment: The while loop is totally unnecessary if the only command is `echo`, but I presume there is more happening in the real script, which is held by the placeholder: `#code for passing id to other script file as parameter`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need this, awk can recognize white space automatically.

```
awk '{print $1}' sample.txt
```

Comment: And how exactly does this print the first 5 chars of every line of sample.txt?

Comment: You see, vanda answer the question with similar way, this makes sense for you now? sometimes, the requesters didn't know how to express their request properly.

Comment: hehe, you really focus on it, Rep is nothing.

Comment: +1: In the case specified in the question, the first 5 characters are also the first field of space delimited text, so this answer is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah, vanda explained it. Thanks for your explanation too.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following simple example:

```
while read line; do id=$(echo $line | head -c5); echo $id; done < file
```

where `head -c5` is the right command to get the first 5 characters from the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to fetch the first column from file try `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename='sample.txt'

while read -r line
do
  id=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
  echo $id
  #code for passing id to other script file as parameter
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: And how exactly does this print the first 5 chars of every line of sample.txt?

Comment: @RedX `awk` separator each line by (`space` by default) and print the first field (`'{print $1}'`) which is the first 5 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler than the top answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='sample.txt'
while read -r line; do
  id=${line:0:5}
  echo $id
  #code for passing id to other script file as parameter
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` with a capture group that matches the first 5 characters and returns only that group:

```sh
sed -E 's/(.{0,5}).*/\1/' sample.txt
```

`(.{0,5})` greedily matches any character up to 5 times, and creates a capture group.

`.*` matches the rest of the line, because we want to replace the entire line, not just the capture group.

`\1` is a backreference which refers to the first capture group.

So we are capturing the group of 5 characters we want, and then replacing the entire matched line with only that capture group.